# Find the number of 1's digits in a binary representation of a number in JAVA

Tags: java, binary

Hey I am trying to study DS&A and I have tried to understand this problem but I don't understand it. I have looked at other forms but most of them are in other languages. Can someone please explain this problem to me in easiest simple form of JAVA.
Thank you

Comment: and what does “DS&A” mean?

Comment: Data Structures and Algorithms

Comment: Ok, then it’s not explaining what “this problem” is referring to.

Comment: the problem is "Find the number of 1's digits in a binary representation of a number" and my question is can someone explain it to me in simple easy form of java

Comment: There's a method for this: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#bitCount(int). However, I don't think you're allowed to use that.

Comment: No, Im trying to understand how to write this from scratch.

Comment: For example, “iterate from 0 to 31 and test whether the bit is set and increment your count if the bit is set”. If you want more elaborated algorithms, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/109023/2711488

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sort algorithms and then binary search to count the number of 1.

For ref. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-1s-sorted-binary-array/

For unsorted binary arrays, [Given an unsorted binary array, count number of 1's, where allowed only to check if an entire subarray is all zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812917/given-an-unsorted-binary-array-count-number-of-1s-where-allowed-only-to-check)